# SwiftUI pass Swift code as a parameter for reusable views

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I'm organising my code and I have this custom Button view that I have made:

```
@State var buttonName = ""
@State var imageName = ""

Button(action: {
              // Code that should be passed as a parameter to be run  
            }){
                HStack(spacing: 15){
                    Image(systemName: imageName).resizable().frame(width:40, height: 40)
                    
                    Text(buttonName)
                    Spacer(minLength: 15)
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                }.padding()
                .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
            }
```

With this setup I can reuse this view as such:

```
buttonView(buttonName: "Logout", imageName: "person.fill")
```

However I'd like to also specify code that should be run as a result of clicking the reusable button, e.g.:

```
buttonView(buttonName: "Logout", imageName: "person.fill", action: {Logout()})
```

This would then go onto custom views said buttons should go to upon the user clicking using a Navigation View within the reusable button view's body.

How would I get around this? I tried the state:

```
@State var action = -> Void
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo view for that purpose

```
struct DemoView: View {
    let action: () -> ()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Demo", action: action)
    }
}
```

Note: don't use `@State` wrapper for public view properties!